# Blank White Page in Control Panel

Tags: control-panel, white-screen-of-death

Strange problem has just manifested out of nowhere (seemingly). Basically when trying to edit an existing or publish a new entry in the CP it redirects to a blank page and does not save.

No errors reported when debugging turned on and no errors in server log.

Not sure how to start troubleshooting this one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've found this to be helpful in resolving the "white screen of death", which is usually a fatal error in PHP.

https://gist.github.com/litzinger/5598641

Hope it helps!